# how to access an <a> tag inside a .js table loop?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

HTML:

```
<tr id="header-row">
  <th class="tableheaders" id="t_headersteamlink">steamlink</th>
  <th class="tableheaders" id="t_headername">name</th>
  <th class="tableheaders" id="t_headerbanned">banned?</th>
  <th class="tableheaders" id="t_headerbandate">banDate</th>
  <th class="tableheaders" id="t_headercreator">creator</th>
  <th class="tableheaders" id="t_headercreationdate">creationDate</th>
</tr>

<tr class="datarow">
  <td ><a href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/example">steamcommunity.com/id/example</a></td>
  <td>exampleUser</td>
  <td>yes</td>
  <td>24/06/2021</td>
  <td>exampleCreator</td>
  <td>20/06/2021</td>
</tr>
```

JavaScript:

```
var table = document.getElementById("steamtable");

window.onload = function() {

for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {

    if (row.cells[2].innerText == "yes") {
        row.cells[1].style.color = 'red';
        row.cells[2].style.color = 'red';
        row.cells[3].style.color = 'red';
    }

  }

}
```

So i'm trying to loop trough the table and if the cell containing the 'banned?' value equals 'yes' then i want change the url tag color of that row to red at all times (link, visited and hover).

Technically i know how to change the colors, i just dont know how to access the url tag in this scenario. The javascript i added just changes the colors of some cells, and that works totally fine.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `url tag` means a tag?

Comment: yes url tag means a tag. i wanted to put the 'a' inside angled brackets but then it doesn't show up at all. sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work if you add the style to the `a` tag inside that cell

like so:

```
     row.cells[0].querySelector("a").style.color = "green";
```

The querySelector selects an a element inside the cell

```js
var table = document.getElementById("steamtable");
window.onload = function() {

for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {

    if (row.cells[2].innerText == "yes") {
       row.cells[0].querySelector("a").style.color = "red";
      
    }

  }

}
```

```html
<table border id="steamtable">
<tr id="header-row">
  <th class="tableheaders" id="t_headersteamlink">steamlink</th>
  <th class="tableheaders" id="t_headername">name</th>
  <th class="tableheaders" id="t_headerbanned">banned?</th>
  <th class="tableheaders" id="t_headerbandate">banDate</th>
  <th class="tableheaders" id="t_headercreator">creator</th>
  <th class="tableheaders" id="t_headercreationdate">creationDate</th>
</tr>

<tr class="datarow">
  <td ><a href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/example">steamcommunity.com/id/example</a></td>
  <td>exampleUser</td>
  <td>yes</td>
  <td>24/06/2021</td>
  <td>exampleCreator</td>
  <td>20/06/2021</td>
</tr>
  
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `getElementsByTagName` to get a element by tag name.

`row.cells[0]` just is a [HTML elements reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element) . Just find a tag inside this element and update the stag style as you did.

```js
const table = document.getElementById("steamtable");

window.onload = function () {
  for (let i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
    if (row.cells[2].innerText == "yes") {
      row.cells[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].style.color = 'red';
      row.cells[1].style.color = 'red';
      row.cells[2].style.color = 'red';
      row.cells[3].style.color = 'red';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="steamtable">
<tr id="header-row">
  <th class="tableheaders" id="t_headersteamlink">steamlink</th>
  <th class="tableheaders" id="t_headername">name</th>
  <th class="tableheaders" id="t_headerbanned">banned?</th>
  <th class="tableheaders" id="t_headerbandate">banDate</th>
  <th class="tableheaders" id="t_headercreator">creator</th>
  <th class="tableheaders" id="t_headercreationdate">creationDate</th>
</tr>

<tr class="datarow">
  <td ><a href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/example">steamcommunity.com/id/example</a></td>
  <td>exampleUser</td>
  <td>yes</td>
  <td>24/06/2021</td>
  <td>exampleCreator</td>
  <td>20/06/2021</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'd suggest using [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector), as it returns a single element instead of an array and is a more modern approach.